# Importing XSD and data into R

Tags: r, xsd, xml-parsing

I generated a XML output from a database (MSSQL2014) and now would like to consume the data as well as the XSD schema information into a R data frame.

Data Source: `MSSQL2014 - AdventureWorks2014 database`

Query executed:

```
select top 1 * 
from person.person as p
  join person.EmailAddress as ea on p.businessEntityID = ea.businessentityID
  join person.PersonPhone as pphone on p.businessEntityID = pphone.businessentityID
for XML AUTO, ELEMENTS, XMLSCHEMA('person');
```

Below is the File generate.  I tried this R code to import but it is unsuccessful.  Does anyone have a guide/tip to point me to the right direction?

RCode:

```
library(XML)
(xml_data <- xmlParse(gsub("&thinsp;", "", "C:\\dissertation\\smta\\indata\\01_Source_Query.XML", fixed = TRUE), asText = TRUE))

xml_attrib <- xpathSApply(doc=xml, path="//person",  xmlAttrs)

df2 <- data.frame(t(xml_attrib))
df2
```

```
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="person" xmlns:schema="person" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:sqltypes="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes" schemaLocation="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/sqltypes/sqltypes.xsd" />
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ContactInfo" />
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ContactRecord" />
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ContactTypes" />
  <xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/IndividualSurvey" />
  <xsd:element name="p">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="BusinessEntityID" type="sqltypes:int" />
        <xsd:element name="PersonType">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="2" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="NameStyle" type="sqltypes:bit" sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks2014].[dbo].[NameStyle]" />
        <xsd:element name="Title" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="8" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="FirstName">
          <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks2014].[dbo].[Name]">
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="50" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="MiddleName" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks2014].[dbo].[Name]">
            <xsd:restri ction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="50" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="LastName">
          <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks2014].[dbo].[Name]">
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="50" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Suffix" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="10" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="EmailPromotion" type="sqltypes:int" />
        <xsd:element name="AdditionalContactInfo" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:complexType sqltypes:xmlSchemaCollection="[AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[AdditionalContactInfoSchemaCollection]">
            <xsd:complexContent>
              <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:xml">
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:any processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ContactInfo http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ContactRecord http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/ContactTypes"
                  /></xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Demographics" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:complexType sqltypes:xmlSchemaCollection="[AdventureWorks2014].[Person].[IndividualSurveySchemaCollection]">
            <xsd:complexContent>
              <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:xml">
                <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:any processContents="strict" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/IndividualSurvey" /></xsd:sequence>
              </xsd:restriction>
            </xsd:complexContent>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd :element name="rowguid" type="sqltypes:uniqueidentifier" />
        <xsd:element name="ModifiedDate" type="sqltypes:datetime" />
        <xsd:element ref="schema:ea" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /></xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="ea">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="BusinessEntityID" type="sqltypes:int" />
        <xsd:element name="EmailAddressID" type="sqltypes:int" />
        <xsd:element name="EmailAddress" minOccurs="0">
          <xsd:simpleType>
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="50" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="rowguid" type="sqltypes:uniqueidentifier" />
        <xsd:element name="ModifiedDate" type="sqltypes:datetime" />
        <xsd:element ref="schema:pphone" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" /></xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="pphone">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="BusinessEntityID" type="sqltypes:int" />
        <xsd:element name="PhoneNumber">
          <xsd:simpleType sqltypes:sqlTypeAlias="[AdventureWorks2014].[dbo].[Phone]">
            <xsd:restriction base="sqltypes:nvarchar" sqltypes:localeId="1033" sqltypes:sqlCompareOptions="IgnoreCase IgnoreKanaType IgnoreWidth" sqltypes:sqlSortId="52">
              <xsd:maxLength value="25" /></xsd:restriction>
          </xsd:simpleType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="PhoneNumberTypeID" type="sqltypes:int" />
        <xsd:element name="ModifiedDate" type="sqltypes:datetime" /></xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
<p xmlns="person">
  <BusinessEntityID>1</BusinessEntityID>
  <PersonType>EM</PersonType>
  <NameStyle>0</NameStyle>
  <FirstName>Ken</FirstName>
  <MiddleName>J</MiddleName>
  <LastName>Sánchez</LastName>
  <EmailPromotion>0</EmailPromotion>
  <Demographics>
    <IndividualSurvey xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/IndividualSurvey">
      <TotalPurchaseYTD>0</TotalPurchaseYTD>
    </IndividualSurvey>
  </Demographics>
  <rowguid>92C4279F-1207-48A3-8448-4636514EB7E2</rowgu id>
    <ModifiedDate>2009-01-07T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
    <ea>
      <BusinessEntityID>1</BusinessEntityID>
      <EmailAddressID>1</EmailAddressID>
      <EmailAddress>ken0@adventure-works.com</EmailAddress>
      <rowguid>8A1901E4-671B-431A-871C-EADB2942E9EE</rowguid>
      <ModifiedDate>2009-01-07T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
      <pphone>
        <BusinessEntityID>1</BusinessEntityID>
        <PhoneNumber>697-555-0142</PhoneNumber>
        <PhoneNumberTypeID>1</PhoneNumberTypeID>
        <ModifiedDate>2009-01-07T00:00:00</ModifiedDate>
      </pphone>
    </ea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer the rest/xml2 package for parsing files.

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
page<-read_html("C:\\dissertation\\smta\\indata\\01_Source_Query.XML")

persons<-html_nodes(page,  xpath = "//p")

fieldnames<-xml_name(xml_find_all(persons, ".//*"))
fields<-xml_text(xml_find_all(persons, ".//*"))
df<-data.frame(fieldnames, fields)
```

The file seems to be interested as html.  The code above reads the data file finds the paragraph tag

for the persons and extracts the field names and values and places them into a data frame.  If there are multiple persons in your file then the lines defining field names and values will need to be vectorized (most likely with supply).  Some clean-up is required to remove a few extraneous rows added to the final data frame.
Good luck.

Comment: This is worked so well- thank you so much. 
When I extracted the XML for 150 persons, the code seemed to get the information as expected - I must've missed what to look for when said to clean-up to remove extraneous rows added to data frame.

Why the need to be vectorized ?